# auto logout in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel 5.1, so I don't know how to log out a authenticated user after few minutes of inactivity. I read many sources about session.php that tells that 'lifetime' is responsible for the same. I set the values as:-

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

but still my session is not getting expired and logging out after a minute. Even when I close the tab its not logging out. Please I need help in this. Is there a table to store session or what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

'lifetime' => 1 means session will expire after 1 minute
by default its 2 hours 120

Another thing which does not allow user to logout is `remember me`
When you authenticate the user you would might passing and remember me parameter which does not allow user to expire.

Comment: I want it to log out automatically after 1 minute. But that is not happening. And my 'remember me' check box is never checked. Even in the database 'remember me' token field is blank.

Comment: i don't think so that there would be anything else you would be passing token can i have your authentication code.

Comment: I did exactly what is given in the documentation for authentication. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
/app/config/session.php

'lifetime' => 1,

'expire_on_close' => false,


_in command prompt 

user@dev MINGW32 /f/xampp/htdocs/conference-room
$ composer dumpautoload 
Generating autoload files
```

_wrote composer dumpautoload , then after that, start server(php artisan serve) to take effect.